# How to update PHPMailer and check installed version

Tags: phpmailer

I need to update PHPMailer on few servers if any old version was installed.
How to check installed version
How to update it to PHPMailer 5.2.20 (for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you installed it. If you're using the recommended method of using [composer](https://getcomposer.org), then a simple `composer update` will get you the latest version. Your `composer.lock` file will show you which version you currently have, or you can open the `VERSION` file which will show you the version number you've got - or if you have a very old version that predates the `VERSION` file, look in the source files instead - they will also say what version they are. If you've installed it manually, just [download the latest version from Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and replace your current version.

Comment: I don't even know if PHPMailer is installed on those servers.
Looks like composer is not installed
root@random:~# composer
-bash: composer: command not found

Comment: OK, so just search for one of its files from a shell: `find / -name class.phpmailer.php`, or use `locate` if you have that installed.

Comment: Thank you, looks like PHPMailer wasn't installed because `find / -name class.phpmailer.php` doesn't return anything. `find` works (checked on another files).